# Undertanding of $f^{(n)}(x)=P_{n}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) e^{-\frac{1}{x}}, \quad(x \neq 0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives

Exercise: Let $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ for $x \neq 0$. Show that for all natural numbers $n$ we have
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=P_{n}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) e^{-1 / x}, \quad(x \neq 0)
$$
where for each $n, P_{n}(t)$ is a polynomial in the variable $t$ of degree $2 n .$ Find a recurrence formula for $P_{n}(t)$

Proof: $$f^{(1)}=e^{\frac{-1}{x}}\frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$f^{(2)}=e^{\frac{-1}{x}}(\frac{1}{x^4}-2\frac{1}{x^3})$$
$$f^{(3)}=e^{\frac{-1}{x}}(\frac{1}{x^6}-6\frac{1}{x^5}+6\frac{1}{x^4})$$
Based on these calculations, we predict that f is n times differentiable for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $$
f^{(n)}(x)=P_{n}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) e^{-1 / x}, \quad(x \neq 0)
$$ where $P$ is a polynomial. Now we proceed to prove this conclusion by induction. The conclusion is true for $n = 1$ as shown above. Given that the conclusion is true for some $n \in \mathbb{N}, 
 x\neq 0$  we have
$$
f^{(n+1)}(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}} P^{\prime}_n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{x^{2}} P_n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) e^{-\frac{1}{x}}=:P_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) e^{-\frac{1}{x}}
$$

Following induction procedure mechanically I did it. But I am confused to understand logic. What have I proved?-Exsistence of some kind of polynome?? And second question: If that is true, from this I can extract recursive formula for $P_{n}(t)$ Again I should prove it by induction??

Comment: You've proven the existence of a sequence of polynomials with $P_1(x)=x^2$ and following a recursive formula linking $P_{n+1}$, $P_n$ and $P'_n$

Comment: It can be said that exercise is done??

Comment: Define the sequence of polynomials $P_n$ recursively, using the recursion formula that you discovered. . Then show that by induction that (a) each $P_n$ has degree $2n$ and (b) $f^{(n)}(x) = P_n(x^{-1}) e^{-1/x}$. Convince yourself that this proves everything. You have done most of the required work, it just need to be presented in an organized way.